# Requests-html package does not render properly for fast.com

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests-html

I am developing a web-scraping app using python 3.7. I am using requests-html for parsing data. Up until now, I have tried the following code which tries to use the render function (since speed data on fast.com is loaded through javascript).

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
quote_page = 'https://fast.com'
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get(quote_page)
r.html.render()
extract_value = r.html.find('#speed-value', first=True)
print(extract_value.text)
```

`speed-value` is the id attribute used by the div that contains the speed data.

But it still prints speed-value as 0.

Comment: Why make things so complicated,  check the internet speed in python itself.

Answer (score 9):

Speed test need a few seconds, you need wait a few seconds after initial render, so specify a sleep param to render function, which means how many long to sleep after initial render.

For example: Modify `r.html.render()` to `r.html.render(sleep=10)`

Tested in my PC,I got a speed number.

Comment: OP should have accepted this as the answer as it solved my issue. Specifically, I needed to induce a delay so any requests made on the page being scraped could complete. The documentation for `requests_html` should make this clearer as it will be an issue on many sites.